# Order of a subgroup of $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_P)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I've been trying to solve the following problem

> Let $n\geq 2$ and $T\leq GL_n(\mathbb{F}_P)$ be the subgroup of
>   $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_P)$ having all upper triangular matrices with all the
>   entries in the diagonal as 1, i.e.
>
> $$ T = \left\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 &a_{12} &a_{13} &\dots &a_{1n}\\ 0 &1
> &a_{23} &\dots &a_{2n}\\ 0 &0 &1 &\dots &a_{3n}\\ \vdots &\vdots
>  &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\ 0 &0 &0 &\dots &1\\ \end{bmatrix} :
>  a_{ij}\in\mathbb{F}_p \right\} $$
>
> Let $N(T)$ be the normalizer of $T$, then we have
>
> $$ \left| N(T) \right| = (p-1)^np^{n(n-1)/2} $$

I got to the result

$$ \left| N(T) \right| = (p-1)^{(n-1)}p^{n(n-1)/2} $$

But I think maybe this is really the case, and the problem is wrong, am I right?

Comment: Are you counting in SL(n) or GL(n) ?

Comment: $GL(n)$, I already understood it, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Orangeskid asks in the comments: where are you doing your counting?

The normalizer $N(T)$ is the subgroup of all upper triangular matrices:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}&\cdots&a_{1n}\\0&a_{22}&\cdots&a_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\
0&0&\cdots&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}.
$$ 
Since the diagonal entries of a matrix in $N(T)$ must be nonzero, you have $(p-1)^n$ choices for these entries, giving the result stated in the problem.

If you are counting in $SL(n)$, you have complete freedom to choose the first $n-1$ diagonal entries, but the determinant 1 condition forces the last entry to be $a_{nn}=\prod a_{ii}^{-1}$. This gives your count.

Comment: I see what I did wrong, thanks! I was counting in $SL(n)$.